# Regex to match all us phone number formats

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

First of all i would say i have seen many example here and googled but none found that matches all the condition i am looking for some match top 3 not below some inbetween.
Kindly let me know how to put all of them in one place.

```
(xxx)xxxxxxx
(xxx) xxxxxxx
(xxx)xxx-xxxx
(xxx) xxx-xxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxx-xxx-xxxxx
```

Using as :

```
  const string MatchPhonePattern =
           @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}";
            Regex rx = new Regex(MatchPhonePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // Find matches.
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
            // Report the number of matches found.
            int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
            // Report on each match.

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {

                tempPhoneNumbers= match.Value.ToString(); ;

             }
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
3087774825
(281)388-0388
(281)388-0300
(979) 778-0978
(281)934-2479
(281)934-2447
(979)826-3273
(979)826-3255
1334714149
(281)356-2530
(281)356-5264
(936)825-2081
(832)595-9500
(832)595-9501
281-342-2452
1334431660
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}`

Comment: hey works perfectly :) , just a question is is good to add the one with xxxxxxxxxx as i think it might be taking random numbers is that possible? google analytic numbers etc?

Comment: It will also capture any string of numbers that is 10 digits long, whether or not that is the behavior you want is up to you, it might be worth having some sort of validation for numbers that are matched by the regular expression if you choose to allow them though.

Comment: Ironically out of several SO answers, this one best meets my needs, so thanks for answering. FYI, I am interested in matching dots and spaces as well, so `\(?\d{3}\)?[. -]? *\d{3}[. -]? *[. -]?\d{4}` did the trick for me.

Comment: I want to restrict it to 1234567890,123-456-7890 only. Then what would be the regex I don't know much about regex

Comment: The following should return false (for more than 10 digits in phone number), but returns true:

Regex.IsMatch("(012)34568902", @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}" )
Regex.IsMatch("01234568902", @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}" )
?Regex.IsMatch("012 345 68902", @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}" )

This should give you what you need: @"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"
http://www.authorcode.com/how-to-use-regular-expression-for-validating-phone-numbers-in-net/

Comment: This regex doesn't work correctly if you have more than 4-digits on the last set. For example, (202) 332-30000, (202) 332-300000000 and (202) 332-33030303 are all valid matches using this regex. This works better @"^((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}$"

Answer (score 12):

```
 public bool IsValidPhone(string Phone)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone))
                return false;
            var r = new Regex(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.●]?([0-9]{3})[-.●]?([0-9]{4})$");
            return r.IsMatch(Phone);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

To extend upon FlyingStreudel's correct answer, I modified it to accept '.' as a delimiter, which was a requirement for me.

`\(?\d{3}\)?[-\.]? *\d{3}[-\.]? *[-\.]?\d{4}`

in use (finding all phone numbers in a string):

```
string text = "...the text to search...";
string pattern = @"\(?\d{3}\)?[-\.]? *\d{3}[-\.]? *[-\.]?\d{4}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regex.Match(text);
while (match.Success)
{
    string phoneNumber = match.Groups[0].Value;
    //TODO do something with the phone number
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To add to all of the above suggestions, here's my RegEx that will enforce NANP standards:

```
((?:\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|(?:(?=0)0[1-9]|\d{2}))\)?\D{0,3})(?:\(?[2-9](?:(?=1)1[02-9]|\d{2})\)?\D{0,3})\d{4})
```

This regular expression enforces NANP Standard rules such as `N11 codes are used to provide three-digit dialing access to special services`, and thus excludes them using a conditional capture. It also accounts for up to 3 non-digit characters (`\D{0,3}`) in between sections, because I've seen some funky data.

From the provided testing data, here's the Output:

```
3087774825
(281)388-0388
(281)388-0300
(979) 778-0978
(281)934-2479
(281)934-2447
(979)826-3273
(979)826-3255
(281)356-2530
(281)356-5264
(936)825-2081
(832)595-9500
(832)595-9501
281-342-2452
```

Note that there were two sample values omitted due to not being valid phone numbers by NANP Standards: Area Code begins with 1

```
1334714149
1334431660
```

The rule I am referring to can be found on the National NANPA's website's Area Codes page stating, `The format of an area code is NXX, where N is any digit 2 through 9 and X is any digit 0 through 9.`

Comment: Looking at the table on wikipedia here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan , it seems that this regex does not exactly match the pattern described.  That being said, it does correctly exclude service codes and is a closer approximation of the NANP standard than any other regex provided in other answers.  This is a very useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Help yourself. Dont use a regex for this. Google release a great library to handle this specific use case: [libphonenumber](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/). There is an [online demo of the lib](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html).

```
public static void Main()
{
    var phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
    var numberProto = phoneUtil.Parse("(979) 778-0978", "US");
    var formattedPhone = phoneUtil.Format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
    Console.WriteLine(formattedPhone);
}
```

[Demo on .NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qHaWHP)

Answer (score 2):

I would approach the situation a bit differently and instead:

- Step 1: extract the numbers you need from the given text. (skip if you have a list of numbers)
- Step 2: Loop the numbers and clean up the format
- Note: The last number is malformed but the code takes only the usable part.

---

Sample Text

```
Here are a list of contacts you can call:
Justin at +11 (949) 255 6458 or 1-909-885-4469.
Smith at (855) 270 4206 or 555-555-5555.
Sammy at 767.456.5289 or 9876548521x355.
Jill at 254.8695 or 56-852-6645 ext 22
```

Code

```js
// Step 1: Match numbers from text;
let likePhoneRegex = /([0-9][0-9\s\.\-\(\)\[\]]+[0-9]{4})(\s*?(x|ext|extension)\s*[0-9]{2,})?/gi;
let matchData = sample.match(likePhoneRegex);

// Step 2: Loop and clean up numbers;
let phoneRegex = /(([0-9]*?)([2-9][0-9]{2})?([2-9][02-9]{2})([0-9]{4}))\b/;
let cleanupRegex = /(\+\.\.?)|(\+.*?\.\.)/;
let cleanData = [];
for( var i=0, il=matchData.length, num; i<il; i++){
   num = matchData[i].replace(/[^0-9\x]/g,'')
   var [ phone, ext ] = num.split('x');
   cleanData.push( phone.replace( phoneRegex, "+$2.$3.$4.$5" ).replace( cleanupRegex, '' ) + ( ext && ext.length > 0 ? ' x' + ext : '' ) );
}
```

Result

```json
[
   "+11.949.255.6458",
   "+1.909.885.4469",
   "855.270.4206",
   "555.555.5555",
   "767.456.5289",
   "987.654.8521 x355",
   "254.8695",
   "852.6645 x22"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^?\(?\d{3}?\)??-??\(?\d{3}?\)??-??\(?\d{4}?\)??-?$
```

This allows:

- (123)-456-7890
- 123-456-7890

Comment: so how do I use it?

Answer (score 1):

for c#, the for US phone number validation  should be like below

```
^\(?\d{3}?\)??-??\(?\d{3}?\)??-??\(?\d{4}?\)??-?$
```

> 777-777-7777

Answer (score 1):

May be I am too late answering here but I have appended country code as prefix. People outside the state/country needs to add this code prior to phone number.I have made country code optional and one may enter the code inside small braces, without braces, with or without plus sign, hyphen as a delimiter to separate from rest of phone number. Regex and their samples are as follows:-

```
regex = '\(?\+?\d{1}\)\?\-?\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}';
Acceptable Samples :
(+1)-(111)-222-7878
+1-(111)-222-7878
+1(111)-222-7878
+1-111-222-7878
+1111-222-2323
1111-222-1212
1-111-222-1212
(111)-111-2232
111-222-3333
If you want to make country code mandatory then use following:-
regex = '\(?\+?\d{1}\)\?-?\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}';
```

Comment: this is not working for me somehow

Answer (score 1):

```
((\+\d[- .]?)?\(?\d{3}\)?[- .]?/?\d{3}[- ./]?\d{4}([ ]?(x|ext|extension)[.]?[ ]?\d{4})?)|(^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}[./-]\d{4} x\d{1,4}$)|(?:(?:\+?1[-. ])?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}|\d{10})\b|\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b|\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}\b|\b\d{3}\/\d{3}-\d{4}\b|\b\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\.\d{4}\b|\b\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\/\d{4}\b|\b\(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{4}\b|\b1[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{3}[-. ]?\d{4}
```

This will match

```
917.974.4266
(123) 456-7890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
123/456-7890
1234567890
+1 (123) 456-7890
+1 123-456-7890
+1 123.456.7890
+1 123/456-7890
+11234567890
(123) 456.7890
(123) 456/7890
(123) 456 7890
1-123-456-7890
1.123.456.7890
1/123/456/7890
1 123 456 7890
1 123.456.7890
1 123/456-7890
123 4567890
123/4567890
123-4567890
123.4567890
(123) 456.7890 ext. 1234
(123) 456-7890 ext. 1234
123-456-7890 ext. 1234
123.456.7890 ext. 1234
123/456-7890 ext. 1234
1234567890 ext. 1234
+1 (123) 456-7890 ext. 1234
+1-123-456-7890
+1 123-456-7890
+1.123.456.7890
+1/123/456/7890
+11234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
123/456-7890
1234567890
(123) 456-7890
(123)456-7890
(123)4567890
(123) 456.7890
(123) 456/7890
(123) 456 7890
1-123-456-7890
1.123.456.7890
1/123/456/7890
1 123 456 7890
1 123.456.7890
1 123/456-7890
123 4567890
123/4567890
123-4567890
123.4567890
(123) 456-7890 ext. 1234
(123) 456.7890 ext. 1234
(123) 456/7890 ext. 1234
123-456-7890 ext. 1234
123.456.7890 ext. 1234
123/456-7890 ext. 1234
1234567890 ext. 1234
+1-123-456-7890 ext. 1234
+1 123-456-7890 ext. 1234
+1.123.456.7890 ext. 1234
+1/123/456/7890 ext. 1234
+11234567890 ext. 1234
(123) 456-7890 x1234
(123) 456.7890 x1234
(123) 456/7890 x1234
123-456-7890 x1234
123.456.7890 x1234
123/456-7890 x1234
1234567890 x1234
+1-123-456-7890 x1234
+1 123-456-7890 x1234
+1.123.456.7890 x1234
+1/123/456/7890 x1234
+11234567890 x1234
123-456-7890 x1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to allow below formats only

- 0123456789
- (123)456-7890
- (123) 456-7890
- 1234567890
- 123-456-67897

string MatchPhonePattern = @"^(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{10}|(\d{3})\s?\d{3}-\d{4})$"

Comment: Did you test your regex pattern? It matches only the first and fourth example. There are several already working answers posted on this question over the years, so new answers should provide something that the others don't. I do not see that in this answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32890320)