# C# removing whitespaces and hyphe

Tags: c#

Hi i am a beginner c# programmer.

Need help in writing small code program console in inviting the user to enter their phone number without spaces and hyphens (-) Do the validation and if the user has not respected those conditions, display an error message. And create a loop that will re-ask the user to enter same infos to try again.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your phone no.: \t");
            string n = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '-' };
            string textBox = Convert.ToString(n);
            string[] numtel = textBox.Split(delimiters);
            bool test = false;
```

Comment: What bit do you need help with?

Comment: You could allow spaces/- and just remove them when they are submitted ...

Answer (score 1):

You need a while loop:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', '-' };
string n;
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your phone no.: \t");
    n = Console.ReadLine();

    if(n.Length > 0 && !n.Any(delimiters.Contains)) break;
    else Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, try again.");
}
```

Comment: Might want to put an else of that condition to show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain solution of your task:

```
bool isValid = false;

while(!isValid){
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your phone no.: \t");
  string phone = Console.ReadLine();  
  isValid = !string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(phone) 
            && phone.s.IndexOfAny(new[] { '-', ' ' }) < 0;
  if (!isValid)
     Console.WriteLine("No spaces or '-' allowed");
}
```

However this is a poor way of validating a phone number. People use '(', '.' and possibly other characters.

Another way is to use a regex, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091324/regex-to-match-all-us-phone-number-formats):

```
  isValid = !string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(phone)
             && Regex.IsMatch(phone, @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var compareStrings = new [] { "-", " " };
string phoneNo=string.Empty;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter phone number without spaces and hyphens ");
    phoneNo = Console.ReadLine();
}while(!(compareStrings.Any((c=>phoneNo.Contains(c)))));
```