# Phone number confirmation with AWS SNS in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm looking for a way to validate a phone number using AWS SNS in my asp.net core app but I cannot find any resource on this matter. Can someone explain how to do this using AWS SDK for .NET ?

Comment: Phone number for an account with Cognito for example? Why SNS in particular? Text? Email? Call? Please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

as @Ermiya Eskandary suggested, more information is needed.

It sounds like you are publishing an sms text message in this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/example_sns_PublishTextSMS_section.html
It also sounds like you are trying to validate a phone number before using `psms_req.SetPhoneNumber(phone_number);`

There are several methods for validating a phone number, the most simple is using regex, the second is by using a reverse lookup. AWS offers [AWS PinPoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/phone-number-validate.html) which will allow you to do a reverse lookup.

Alternatively you can use a simple regex, [Regex to match all us phone number formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091324/regex-to-match-all-us-phone-number-formats)

[AWS SDK AmazonPinpointClient.PhoneNumberValidate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Pinpoint/MPinpointPhoneNumberValidatePhoneNumberValidateRequest.html)

[Amazon SNS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html)